# Encrypting and decrypting in Go

Tags: go, encryption

I have a next page token that I return in my API response, but I want to encrypt this using a keyphrase.

Currently, I have the following logic:

```
func encryptToken(value []byte, keyPhrase string) []byte {
    aesBlock, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(mdHashing(keyPhrase)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    gcmInstance, err := cipher.NewGCM(aesBlock)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    nonce := make([]byte, gcmInstance.NonceSize())
    _, _ = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce)

    cipheredText := gcmInstance.Seal(nonce, nonce, value, nil)

    return cipheredText
}
```

This works for me and I can encrypt my token.

I can also decrypt by using the following:

```
func decryptToken(ciphered []byte, keyPhrase string) []byte {
    hashedPhrase := mdHashing(keyPhrase)
    aesBlock, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(hashedPhrase))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    gcmInstance, err := cipher.NewGCM(aesBlock)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    nonceSize := gcmInstance.NonceSize()
    nonce, cipheredText := ciphered[:nonceSize], ciphered[nonceSize:]
    originalText, err := gcmInstance.Open(nil, nonce, cipheredText, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return originalText
}
```

However, the problem is, I will be encrypting the token in one API call and then decrypting it in the following call - so I will not have access to the `nonceSize` value between different calls.

Is there a means of solving this issue? Or am I misunderstanding, and the nonce value will be the same in all calls as long as the keyphrase is the same?

Comment: *...so I will not have access to the nonceSize value between different calls...* Do you mean *nonceSize* or *nonce*? When using `NewGCM()`, the nonce size is 12 bytes, which also corresponds to the *recommended* nonce size for GCM (other nonce sizes can be specified with `NewGCMWithNonceSize()`, but this should only be done for compelling reasons). The nonce is not secret and is therefore passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext (usually concatenated) where nonce and ciphertext can be separated due to the *agreed* nonce size.

Comment: Apologies, I mean the nonce - I'm quite new to this as you can tell.
Will the nonce value remain consistent across calls?
I'm worried the following will happen:
1. Api is called, new token created and encoded with a nonce `X`
2. Client returns the token as part of their next request, decode logic tries to decode the token but the nonce is no longer `X`
Is this something that is likely to happen?

Comment: Yes, but the nonce doesn't need to remain secret, so normally it is included with the ciphertext; usually it is prepended and if it has a fixed size then the first 12 bytes can simply be stripped out or read from a stream.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you

Comment: A message number or serial nonce may also be used in some protocols, so these lower level API's usually do not automatically prefix the nonce by themselves. By the way, it seems that you are already prefixing the nonce, so you seem to be good.